# Tapkey Android: How to fetch current status of lock i.e. its locked or open

Tags: android, sdk, tapkey

Thank you for Tapkey Android SDK.

In our application, it's required to show the current status of lock i.e. its locked or open. I have gone through entire documentation at https://developers.tapkey.io/mobile/android/getting_started/, but I cannot find any ways to fetch this status, can you please help here.

Answer (score 0):

The current available locks are technical incapable to detect the bolting state. In the end, the electronics just engage a clutch for a short amount of time. In this time range the mechanical movement is done by hand. Because of this, there is currently no public api for to detecting the bolting state.

For lock manufacturers it is possible to report such a status, which then can be evaluated by the Tapkey Mobile SDK. In this case, please contact Tapkey directly for more information.

The default duration how long a lock is enabled to lock/unlock depends on the lock itself. For the Tapkey-Dom cylinders this is 8 seconds, but this might change in future firmware versions.

Additional to the `DefaultTriggerLockCommand` there is a `TemporaryUnlockTriggerLockCommand` which can be created with the `TemporaryTriggerUnlockCommandBuilder`. With this command it is possible to specify the duration. But be aware that this command might be rejected by older locks.

Comment: Thank you Harald for your reply. I got your point. 
Do you know the duration for which lock is in UNLOCK state? We can manage our UI if we know this duration exactly.

Comment: Added the information about the unlock duration in the answer